# specify signed attributes with OpenSSL in PKCS7 signature

Tags: pdf, openssl

I am evaluating the capability of **openssl** for generating *PDF signatures*. I see some differences between the *PKCS7* signature fields generated by *openssl* and other programs.

How can I specify exactly which **signedAttr** fields would be included in the signature ?

For example, here is three-way comparison via [meld](http://meldmerge.org/):

```
$ meld <(openssl cms -inform DER -cmsout -print -in minimal_signed_pdfbox.pkcs7) \
       <(openssl cms -inform DER -cmsout -print -in minimal_signed_adobe.pkcs7)  \
       <(openssl cms -inform DER -cmsout -print -in minimal.pkcs7)
```

[image]

**Left side**: **minimal_signed_pdfbox.pkcs7** generated by [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) (it uses [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)) this way:

```
java -jar pdfbox-sign.jar JohnSmith.pem <PASSWORD> minimal.pdf
```

- extract the PKCS7 to *minimal_signed_pdfbox.pkcs7*

**Center**: **PKCS7** generated by [Adobe Reader DC](https://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/) (it uses [Adobe PubSec](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/pdfl_sdk/9/PDFL_SDK9_HTMLHelp/API_References/Acrobat_API_Reference/Digital_Signatures/PubSec.html)) this way:

- Create a *digital ID* from the file **JohnSmith.pfx**
- Sign the document with that *digital ID*
- Save the result as in *minimal_signed_adobe.pdf*
- extract the PKCS7 to *minimal_signed_adobe.pkcs7*

**Right**: **PKCS7** generated by **OpenSSL** this via **command line**:

```
openssl cms -sign -signer JohnSmith.pem -binary -in minimal.pdf -outform der -out minimal.pkcs7
```

In the first two cases the **pkcs7** was extracted from the **pdf** using the [peepdf](http://eternal-todo.com/tools/peepdf-pdf-analysis-tool) tool.

The [minimal.pdf](https://github.com/yucer/pdf-examples/blob/updating2/minimal.pdf) file being signed is the one described in the standard ISO-32000 in *Annex H.2: Minimal PDF File*.

The rest of the files used and the certificates are zipped here: [so.zip](http://www.filedropper.com/so_1).

The **signature** and **messageDigest** fields are different because:

1. Adobe linearizes the file before starting (changing also the PDF version)
2. The signed PKCS7 attributes (**signedAttrs**) included in every case is different (and they are included in the calculation)
3. In the real scenario, the PDF need extra objects to include the signature,    that are not present in this case, for simplification.

Signing a **PDF** is not only to generate the signature, it is also to embed it into the file. But now I am focused on the signature format (2)

Once the *smime capabilities* are excluded:

```
openssl cms -nosmimecap -sign -signer JohnSmith.pem -binary -in minimal.pdf -outform der -out minimal_nosmimecap.pkcs7
```

The differences are more clear:

[image]

The remaining differences are:

1. **Adobe** doesn't include the *signingTime* (1.2.840.113549.1.9.5)
2. **pdfbox** specify the extra signed attribute [1.2.840.113549.1.9.52](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.9.52) not recognized by (**openssl asn1parse**) in order to specify the *sha256 encryption* instead of specifying the **signatureAlgorithm/algorithm** as sha256WithRSAEncryption ([1.2.840.113549.1.1.11](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.11))

How can I manage those signed attributes ? Via command line I have only this related parameter:

```
-noattr        don't include any signed attributes
```

the parameter **-nosmimecap** doesn't appear via:

```
openssl cms --help
```

but **it works**, are there other hidden parameters to control that?

I'm using:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```